# jQuery disable/stop vTicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [vTicker](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker), a jQuery plugin that allows you to have a vertical news ticker/scroller on a page.

I don't have any problems getting it to work but I am having problems trying to destroy it.

On my website, I have 6 images in an < li > (necessary for vTicker to work) and 4 < li >
(so a total of 4 rows of 6 images each)

Thing is that when the user resizes the browser, I also resize the images but the vTicker doesn't recalculate the height of the element.

What I need to do is :
1) When the browser is resized, I need to disable / destroy the current instance of vTicker and reinitialize a new one so that it can recalculate the correct heights for each element.

I managed to make it stop by manually editing the vTicket plugin code by adding before the "return"

```
$.fn.extend({
  clear: function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

I can then stop the moving by calling something like

```
$vTicker.clear(); //where $vTicket i defined as $vticker = $('selector').vTicker({...});
```

But then when I try to reinitialize the plugin (creating a new instance), it's as if both my instances become active... so I have twice the movement

Any idea how I would do this ? Let me know if it's unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solution would be to load the ticker via AJAX. This way, when it loads, you can call your `$('#divId').vTicker({...})` and then when the window resized (or you want to refresh it for some other reason), you just remove and reload the entire element and re-apply the vTicker plugin.